# View doesn't get updated Rspec value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

After a factory girl create I have the following

```
it "should display the email of user if public" do

    @user.update_attributes(:public_email => true)
    # I have also tried
    # @user.public_email = true
    # and
    # @user.toggle!(public_email)
    @user.save
    puts "EMAIL IS #{@user.public_email}"
    get :show, :id => @user.id
    response.should have_selector("dt", :content => "Email")

end
```

Rspec will print that "EMAIL IS true" but in the view, public_email is not true (I have `<%= "User email is #{@user.public_email}." %>` and that prints false).

All my other tests work as expected and it works fine in development.

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

This is my own fault. I was trying to avoid writing the line `get :show, :id => @user.id` a bunch of times, so I had another `before(:each) do` call after those tests, and I thought by listing it after them it would not count, but apparently it does.

Comment: Did you mean to have in the view `<%= "User email is #{@user.public_email}." %>`?

Comment: Yes, edit is updated. That part worked, and it told me the email was false.

Comment: Is `public_email` listed as an attribute on the model? Also, does your `update_attributes` line return `true` or `false`

Comment: It is listed, it is attr_accessible, and it returns true.

Comment: Please add your `show` action to the question, and maybe some of the view (please keep it small).

Comment: I figured out my problem, it was my own fault of not knowing how rspec works, I appreciate you all trying to help.